# Confirmation on $2\times 2\times n$ Rubik's cube group

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-actions, rubiks-cube

I believe that I have come up with formulae for the groups representing the $2\times 2\times n$ Rubik's "cubes," but I need someone to confirm that they are correct. Here are the groups that I came up with for the groups in this form (they do not take pure rotations of the cube into account):

- For a $2\times 2\times 2$ cube, the associated group is $\mathbb Z_3^7\rtimes S_8$.
- For a $2\times 2\times (2n+1)$ cube, where $n\ge 1$, the associated group is $S_8^n\times S_4$.
- For a $2\times 2\times 2n$ cube, where $n\ge 2$, the associated group is $S_8^n$.

Can anyone confirm these results, if only for certain small values of $n$?

Comment: Heh, was [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/119894/math-challenges/120574#120574) inspired by your findings?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Of course! I just have to make absolutely sure that my "findings?" are actually "findings."

Comment: are you considering positions similar to this to be valid? https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRUFebgZzY0FP2Gp4n-xKB5niBaxh_WJSSytQmObGyLLugPH0BGFw

Comment: @timidpueo No, only positions in which the square prism is mapped back onto itself.